# Yii TbCarousel onclick link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, onclick, carousel

I am working on development of an web App using Yii. I have set a carousel view on my front page(this  caousel is a widget named Tbcarousel of the bootstrap ) want to make it onclick i.e when I click on the carousel image, it should go to a webpage, I tried by the following code but no change. Useful ideas are welcome.

```
        array('image'=>'images/2.png', 'label'=>'',
        'caption'=>' ',
        'url'=>'www.fortishealthcare.com',
        'src' => 'http://www.fortishealthcare.com',            
        'linkOptions' => array(
        'title' => 'Yii Booster',
        ),
```

Comment: do u need the destination url constant? means for each image the page should redirect to same page?

Comment: that actually differs for all images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Tbcarousel does not provide such facility but you can do it easily. There could be other possible ways but i am suggesting the one i think  is easy.
First add this code to `Tbcarosel`

```
array('image'=>'images/2.png', 'label'=>'',
        'caption'=>' ',
        'src' => 'http://www.fortishealthcare.com',            
        'title' => 'Yii Booster',
         'imageOptions' => array('id'=>'www.fortishealthcare.com')
        ),
```

Now you can use jquery. By default Tbcarousel uses the class `carousel-inner`. And its inner items use the class `item`.
You can write this jquery code like this

```
$(".item").click(function(){
  selectedImage = $(this).find('img');
url=$(selectedImage).attr('id');
window.location =url;
    });
```

As the id of the image is your required url so it will redirect the page to the url.